# How to fix one keyPressed delayed in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, textfield, jlist, autosuggest

**I am trying to developing auto suggest Textfield.**   When i am typing in Textfield it is delay one key and suggest one key late **

> **When i am typing aaa it is querying as 'aa' only and suggest according to that in list.When i am pressing any key after aaa (extra key Press) then it will querying as aaa**

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 239);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

            try {

                addListItem();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    textField.setBounds(71, 24, 86, 20);
    panel.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    list = new JList<String>();

    list.setBounds(71, 55, 86, 97);
    list.setVisible(false);
    list.getScrollableTracksViewportHeight();

    panel.add(list);
}

public void addListItem() throws Exception {

    list.setVisible(true);

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdemo", "root", "root");
    ps = c.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT stud_name FROM student_info where stud_name like '" + textField.getText().trim() + "%' ");
    ResultSet s = ps.executeQuery();

    model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    while (s.next()) {
        model.addElement(s.getString("stud_name"));
        System.out.println(s.getString("stud_name"));

    }
    list.setModel(model);

}
```

Comment: Use `keyReleased` ?

Comment: what should i write in keyReleased ? @Berger

Comment: Just use `keyReleased` INSTEAD of `keyPressed` .

Comment: thank you.it's working. when i cleared textfield it will still show me filled list.how to empty it?

Comment: In `addListItem` check that the textfield is not empty (if it is, do nothing), because if it is empty, your query will match `'%'`, i.e your whole table .

Comment: thank you so much.it's working.

Comment: Note that there may also be better ways to achieve what you want, have a look at `DocumentListener` :  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyReleased` instead of `keyPressed` method of `KeyAdapter` class.

Comment: thank you.it's working. when i cleared textfield it will still show me filled list.

Comment: That's because keyPressed event will be called when you press backspace to clear the textbox, plus there is no logic to remove item from the list. I would suggest add remove logic on backspace key press. something like:
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE){  
        //remove item from the list;

Comment: thank you , i had solved it by checking textfield is empty or not.

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. That is an old API used in AWT. In a Swing application you should be using a `DocumentListener`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Listening For Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more information and examples.